# Sequelize - Postgres - How to create new object from junction table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use a junction table model to create a new object in Sequelize. I have read through the docs pretty thoroughly and do not believe that this use case is covered, unless I am misunderstanding (which is always a possibility).

Docs:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html
https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html

Example code:

```
import { Model as SQLModel } from 'sequelize';

class CarCompany extends SQLModel {};
class BodyStyle extends SQLModel {};
class Model extends SQLModel {};

// A car company can make multiple types of cars
CarCompany.hasMany(BodyStyle);

// A type of car can be made by multiple companies.
// We have a junction table to represent this relationship
BodyStyle.belongsToMany(CarCompany, { through: CarCompanyBodyStyles });

// Each model has only one type that it fits into and only one company that makes it
Model.belongsTo(CarCompanyBodyStyles);

// Now let's create some example car types
const convertible = new BodyStyle({ name: 'Convertible' });
const suv = new BodyStyle({ name: 'SUV' });

// Now let's create some example car companies
const toyota = new CarCompany({ name: 'Toyota' });
const ferrari = new CarCompany({ name: 'Ferrari' });

// Now let's specify which types of cars are made by each company
const toyotaConvertibles = toyota.addBodyStyle(convertible);
const toyotaSUVs = toyota.addBodyStyle(suv);

const ferrariConvertibles = ferrari.addBodyStyle(convertible);

// Now let's define some specific models
const solara = toyotaConvertibles.createModel({ name: 'Solara' });
const rav4 = toyotaSUVs.createModel({ name: 'RAV-4' });

const spider = ferrariConvertibles.createModel({ name: '488 Spider' });

// Now lets see some nested relational objects that we have created:
const toyotaModels = CarCompany.findByPk(
  toyota.id,
  {
    include: [
      {
        all: true,
        nested: true,
      },
    ],
  },
);
const ferrariModels = CarCompany.findByPk(
  ferrari.id,
  {
    include: [
      {
        all: true,
        nested: true,
      },
    ],
  },
);

console.log({ ferrariModels, toyotaModels });
```

What I was hoping to see is something like:

```
{
  ferrariModels: {
    bodyStyles: [
      {
        name: 'Convertible',
        models: [
          { name: '488 Spider' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  toyotaModels: {
    bodyStyles: [
      {
        name: 'SUV',
        models: [
          { name: 'RAV-4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Convertible',
        models: [
          { name: 'Solara' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

But instead I get an error:

```
TypeError: toyotaConvertibles.createModel is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to go about creating this type of relationship?

Comment: I don't see a createModel method anywhere in the sequelize docs. Also, this is not how models are set up(or maybe you just wrote it here this way for brevity?)

Comment: “Model” refers to a model of car. I’ve renamed the Sequelize class Model to SQLModel, you can see at the top. That’s probably confusing, sorry

Comment: The problem is that toyotaConvertibles is a BodyStyle and not a CarCompanyBodyStyles because methods to create/update/delete/read a belongsToMany-association model  are working with a model on the other end of the association and not with a model that is associated with a junction table.

Comment: So then how am I supposed to access the carCompanyBodyStyle that was created when I added a bodyStyle?